# Create and populate array dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of programming language like:

```
const tags = ["js", "ruby", "ios", "python", "go"];
```

I also have a list of users like:

```
const user = [
  {
    "id": "userId_1",
    "language": ["ruby", "ios"]
  }, 
  ...
];
```

Is there a nice way to populate an array named by the language name with the Ids of users?

Something like:

```
const ruby = ["userId_1", "userId_3", "userId_8", ...];
```

Comment: The variable name will not translate, you must scope it.

Comment: he meant `id`, not variable name.

Comment: @WilliamWang I meant that the variable name `ruby` gets erased. You must store it in a scoped name.

Comment: ah, yes, correct. according to my answer, we should call it by output.ruby, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const tags = ["js", "ruby", "ios", "python", "go"];

const user = [
  {
    "id": "userId_1",
    "language": ["ruby", "ios"]
  }, 
  {
    "id": "userId_2",
    "language": ["ruby", "python"]
  }, 
  {
    "id": "userId_3",
    "language": ["go", "ios"]
  }, 
];

const output = user.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.language.forEach(lang => {
    if (!acc[lang]) acc[lang] = [];
    acc[lang].push(cur.id);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You don't even need the tags array right?

Comment: correct for now, just tags will be needed if you needs all the tags in the output to refactor the output.

Comment: Hum, I got something like `{ '[object Object]': [ 'userId_1', 'userId_2',`

Comment: can you run the above code snippet ? result says `{
  "ruby": [
    "userId_1",
    "userId_2"
  ],
  "ios": [
    "userId_1",
    "userId_3"
  ],
  "python": [
    "userId_2"
  ],
  "go": [
    "userId_3"
  ]
}`

Comment: Yeah, nevermind my "real world code" just had a type issue (basically language is an object! Thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 0):

Something shorter would be nice:

```js
const ruby = user.map((user) => user.language.includes("ruby") ? user.id : undefined);
```